# adding i2c device in raspberry pi device tree source

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, raspberry-pi, linux-device-driver, device-tree

I am learning to add i2c devices in device tree of raspberry's kernel 4.4.8. After successful compilation of DT, raspberry pi is not allowing me to log in to board. 
showing "ssh: connect to host 10.1.1.103 port 22: Connection refused".

I have linked dt sources below
[DT Souce](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1PHxtbOmCMpTVFkbG9Vd2NXMHM).

one by one, I tried adding in all following files.

in file bcm2708-rpi-b.dts line 93. (lm75@48).

in file bcm2708-rpi-b-plus.dts line no. 87.

in file bcm2708.dtsi line no. 44.
Please help me. Any help will be appreciated. 
Thanks.

Comment: Did you perform a sanity test, i.e. build (and test) the kernel and DT ***without*** any changes?

Comment: yes, i did. Without any changes it lets me to log in.

Comment: Is that right place (path) to add i2c device in DT ... ???

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.